# Separate Admin Website?

Tags: information-architecture

Is it best to have separate websites for the Data Entry Team and Customer Service Team?

**Data Entry Team** are responsible for inputting the data (adding records).

**Customer Service Team** are responsible for sending out invoices, checking orders, payment, dealing with the customers, etc.

To have separate websites connected to the same database, e.g. data.mycompany.com (login for data entry - different layout/features) and
admin.mycompany.com (login for admin and customer service team - different layout/features), or to have both in one? eg: staff.mycompany.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From an architectural perspective I think a single site would be easier to manage in changing circumstances:

- if the activities are ever switched between roles (if what was a data entry responsibility becomes an admin responsibility)
- if a user ever changes role
- if a user ever holds both roles at once

From a UI perspective, you should be able to avoid clutter in a single site by hiding options (menu items, buttons etc) that do not apply to the user's role.

Comment: I think the two latter circumstances are better handled by adding a separate user identity service that provides authentication, authorization, etc to both sites. You can even use an existing solution, like [Crowd](http://www.atlassian.com/software/crowd/overview).

Answer (score 0):

When you say "separate Website", do you really mean one Website with different UI/Permissions and different entry pages? That would make sense. There is no reason to build anything different.